# Using FLEX with Swift project

Tags: swift, xcode, flex-lexer

Anyone knows how to use Flex in Swift Xcode Project? It is possible with Objective-C, but I really don't know how to utilise Flex and Yacc from a Swift file.
Any help / example is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well it turned out that this is pretty simple. Xcode recognises the Flex files. The only thing needed is to declare the functions (for example yylex()) as extern in a header file and then include it in the bridging header.